# Is the df.plot.line() a matplotlib or seaborn? (Python 3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have those variables to find 5 sum of 5 columns as below:

```
TotalUnitsSold = mmSalesDF['Units Sold'].sum()
TotalUnitsCost = mmSalesDF['Unit Cost'].sum()
TotalRevenue = mmSalesDF['Total Revenue'].sum()
TotalCost = mmSalesDF['Total Cost'].sum()
TotalProfit = mmSalesDF['Total Profit'].sum()
```

I need to create a line plot using matplotlib or seaborn, so I have the code as below:

```
# Create a pandas dataframe with variables above, index is the column names
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Total': [TotalUnitsSold, TotalUnitsCost, TotalRevenue, TotalCost, TotalProfit],
   }, index=['Unit Sold', 'Unit Cost', 'Revenue', 'Cost', 'Profit'])

# Create the line plot 
lines = df.plot.line()
plt.yscale('log')
```

I wonder if the code line

```
lines = df.plot.line()
```

is matplotlib? If it's not, how could I fix it to fulfill the requirement?

Comment: Yes, `DataFrame.plot` uses matplotlib as the back-end by default.

Comment: `mmSalesDF[['Unit Sold', 'Unit Cost', 'Revenue', 'Cost', 'Profit']].sum().plot()` would work...